# How to use jQuery to extract a URL parameter from a string

Tags: jquery, regex, string

i hat one task, and know i have to continue but have a bad experience with regexp ... :(

can somebody help me :

i need to take a sting from "domain url" with jquery :

This is the address name :

```
http://mydomain/Our-Company/default.aspx?txt=James D. Perrlo
```

I want to take with jquery la string after "?txt=" in this case "James D. Perrlo"

PS: This string always is ends of the url

Can somebody help me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This small [URL plugin](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser) lets you do this:

```
var url = $.url('http://allmarkedup.com/folder/dir/index.html?item=value');
url.attr('protocol'); // returns 'http'
url.attr('path'); // returns '/folder/dir/index.html'
```

https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser

Comment: @karim79 do you have a copy of this plugin? The site seems to be down from a long long time.

Comment: New link is alive :) Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

`/.+\?(.[^&]+)/` should do the trick.